# Install multiple ssl certificates spray.io

Tags: scala, spray

I have server writing in spray.io with SSL certificate installed. 
Is it possible to setup additional ssl certificate to spray.io ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It couldn't be done on a host but there is possibility to do it via let's say AWS ELB